# How can I encode pandas with iso-8859-1?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have pandas related problem with encoding.
Here is the line of code:

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=";", encoding='ISO-8859-1', engine = 'python')
```

It works but it replaces letters äÄ and öÖ with "".
How can I get this work?

Answer (score 1):

I would check the encoding of the csv file by doing this:

```
with open("my_data.csv", 'rb') as rawdata:
    result = chardet.detect(rawdata.read(10000))
print(result)
```

It'll return something like:

```
{'encoding': '<some encoding>', 'confidence': a float, 'language': 'finnish'}
```

Then do this:

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=";", encoding='<some encoding>', engine = 'python')
```

where

```
<some encoding> = the encoding of your file
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got it to work with data, but if .csv file column names contain certain letters it can't process them.

Comment: Which characters?